# How to include decimal places in the function range() in R when you subset from a variable those that are distinct to NA

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the range of a variable that has several decimal places and also some of the values are `NA`. An example is:

```
df1<-data.frame(x=c(0.34567,1.34563,1.26745,NA,0.65789,0.903455,1.49567,NA, 0.28749),
                ID=c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A"))

df1
     x ID
1 0.35  A
2 1.35  B
3 1.27  A
4   NA  B
5 0.66  A
6 0.90  B
7 1.50  A
8   NA  B
9 0.29  A
```

I have tried the code below but I get a range without decimal places, and hence, unuseful:

```
range(!is.na(df1$x))

[1] 0 1
```

How should I do it to get several decimal places?

Comment: `range(df1$x, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: And if I want more decimal places than show by defect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `is.na` you get `TRUE`/`FALSE` values

```
!is.na(df1$x)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

and when you take `range` on them `TRUE` is coerced to 1 and `FALSE` to 0. Hence, your `range` is shown as `0`/`1`.

```
range(!is.na(df1$x))
#[1] 0 1
```

If you want to ignore `NA` values there is `na.rm` parameter in `range` which is by default `FALSE`

```
range(df1$x, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 0.28749 1.49567
```

Comment: Perfect explanation, I didn't realize about the output in `!is.na(df1$x)`. As I asked you in other comment, when I run `range(df1$x, na.rm = TRUE)`, I get the range with two decimal places instead of with 5 as you. Is there a easy way to get 5 decimal places in my output?

Comment: @Dekike Run `options(digits = 5)` in the console or increase the number if you want more digits.

Comment: Why, if I run `df1<- data.frame(Num_det= c(4,7,2,4,NA,10,8,0,3,NA,24),
                 SDF= c(1.0214,0.9456,NA,1.3453,0.6782,NA,0.9889,1.3874,0.9999,1.1111,0.389))`, then this `df1<-df1%>%mutate(Std_Num_det=Num_det/SDF)`, then this `df1$Std_Num_det[df1$Std_Num_det>32]<- 32`, and as last, this `range(df1$Std_Num_det, na.rm = TRUE)`, I get this `[1]  0 32`?

Comment: @Dekike What output do you expect then? because your 8th row is 0 the range is from 0 to 32. `na.rm` ignores `NA` values and not 0 values.

Comment: No, I'm expecting decimal places... the range is ok, but I need to know the decimal places... But in this case, although I indicate `na.rm=TRUE` in the range, there is no decimal places in the output. Do you know why? I guess it is something silly.

Comment: since both the numbers in the range are integers it removes the decimals places. Try doing `df1$Std_Num_det[11] <- NA` and then do `range(df1$Std_Num_det, na.rm = TRUE)` you get `range` with decimal places.

Comment: mmmm... It is true. Buuuut.... In my "real" data I can't delete the integer numbers that I include (like the number 32), so, do you know how to do to get decimal places after adding integer numbers to a variable that is numerical and has decimal places? I tried with `df1$Std_Num_det[df1$Std_Num_det>32.0000]<- 32.0000 `, but I still get `[1]  0 32`

Comment: if you want with fixed decimal places, you can use `sprintf`, `sprintf("%05f", range(df1$Std_Num_det, na.rm = TRUE))` but the numbers would be characters. If you want to do some calculations with it convert it to `numeric` and then do it.